# How to register for long press on list item displayed in the drop down menu in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview

I want to do some stuff on the long press of list item displayed in the drop down menu in AutoCompleteTextView. In this case, is it possible to register for long press? If possible, then please provide some reference.

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` from the popup showing the results is hidden in the `AutoCompleteTextView` class so there is no way to access that directly. But you should be able to implement a long click by creating a custom adapter for the `AutoCompleTextView` and setting a `OnLongClickListener` on the row view in the adapter's `getView()` method.

Comment: Hi Luksprog, thanks for the reply. Based on your suggestion, I am able to register for a long click but the basic feature of filtering(displaying relevant items in a drop-down menu) of data is missing. If you have any idea to rectify it, then please share it.

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta Setting a `OnLongClickListener` on the row view in the adapter's `getView()` method shouldn't prevent the `AutoCompleTextView` from showing the drop down. You should post some code with what you're doing.

Comment: I have the same issue. Clicking an item no longer fills the text and the dropdown does not dismiss. The long click listner works though.